# How to call a SelectMethod of ObjectDataSource from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I want to call a method from code behind as the `SelectMethod` of my `ObjectDataSource`  , here is the code :

.aspx :

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS_Step1"
        runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetResults"
        DataObjectTypeName="DefaultPage.MyPackage" TypeName="DefaultPage" />
```

.aspx.cs :

```
public partial class DefaultPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<MyPackage> GetResults()
    {
      // code ...
    }
}
```

When I run the code , I get :

> The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource
>   'ODS_Step1' could not be found.

Any idea what kind of typename should I use , when I want  SelectMethod to be called from the code behind ?

Thanks

Comment: usefull link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311662/asp-net-objectdatasource-update-from-code-behind

Comment: try change `GetResults` to _static_ like `public static List<MyPackage> GetResults()` also see samples from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.typename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ron have you tried fully qualified name `namespace.classname` ?